# has-bouncing="false' is not working in mobile web browser(safari)

Tags: ionic-framework

We are developing a hybrid app using ionic to avoid bouncing in IOS we are used has-bouncing it is working fine for app but not working for IOS web browser

Comment: Hi Mounika, Are you writing has-bouncing="false" inside <ion-content has-bouncing="false"> ion-content ?

Comment: Thanks for replay @KAUSHALJ.SATHWARA

Comment: Thanks for replay @KAUSHALJ.SATHWARA .Yes I am writing has bouncing inside the ion-content